# Pure Python Webcam Access and Recording

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision

I was wondering if there was a way to access a computer's webcam and any usb-attached camera using camera using only python and its builtin modules.

I know that opencv exists and it is by far the best open source computer vision library, but is there any option that just uses Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you ever need that man ? Why ?

Comment: Its because OpenCV can be a pain to compile in some application, for example in FPGAs.